# What's the cleanest way of counting the iteration of a queryset loop?

Tags: python, django, for-loop

I need to loop through a queryset and put the objects into a dictionary along with the sequence number, *i*, in which they appear in the queryset. However a Python *for* loop doesn't seem to provide a sequence number. Therefore I've had to create my own variable *i* and increment it with each loop. I've done something similar to this, is this the cleanest solution?

```
ledgers = Ledger.objects.all()
i = 0

for ledger in ledgers:
    print('Ledger no '+str(i)+' is '+ledger.name)
    i += 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[**`enumerate(…)`** [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) is designed for that:

```
ledgers = Ledger.objects.all()

for i, ledger in enumerate(ledgers):
    print(f'Ledger no {i} is {ledger.name}')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly the answer to your question.

If you'd need the index afterwards at the QuerySet, you can annotate it like that:

```py
from django.db.models import Window, F

ledgers_qs = Ledger.objects.annotate(index=Window(expression=DenseRank(), order_by=F('id').desc()))

# You can iterate over the object indexes and names
for index, name in ledgers_qs.values_list('index', 'name'):
    print('Ledger no '+str(i)+' is '+ledger.name)
    i += 1

# You can make further QuerySet operations if needed
# because ledgers is a QuerySet with annotated indexes:
ledgers_qs.filter(index__lt=5, name__contains='foo')
```

With that you get a queryset that you can use for further database operations.

---

*Why did I create this answer?*

*Because it is often better to work with QuerySet's if possible to be able to enhance the existing code structure without limitations.*

[DenseRank](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/database-functions/#denserank)